# Printing parts of a Pandas groupby output

Tags: python, pandas

Following on from an earlier question [Pandas Percentage count on a DataFrame groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122300/pandas-percentage-count-on-a-dataframe-groupby/32122918#32122918) I have a Dataframe (mydf) in the following format:

```
Index   Feature ID  Stuff1  Stuff2
1       True    1   23      12
2       True    1   54      12
3       False   0   45      67
4       True    0   38      29
5       False   1   32      24
6       False   1   59      39
7       True    0   37      32
8       False   0   76      65
9       False   1   32      12
10      True    0   23      15
..n     True    1   21      99
```

With the help of an answer from my previous question I can calculate percentages of a groupby based on True and False percentages of the 'Feature' for each 'ID' (0 or 1) using this method

```
percentages = pd.DataFrame({'Percentage': mydf.groupby(('ID', 'Feature')).size() / (len(df)*100)})
```

This prints out as:

```
            Percentage
ID Feature            
0  False           20
   True            30
1  False           30
   True            20
```

I can also separate the same method above per 'ID', so for ID 0 I would use the following:

```
percentages = pd.DataFrame({'Percentage': mydf[(mydf['ID'] == 0)].groupby(('ID','Feature')).size() / (len(df))*100})
```

This prints out as:

```
            Percentage
ID Feature            
0  False           20
   True            30
```

My question is how do I then go further and just print single outputs for say ID = 0 and Feature = 'False', so that I can print to different sheets in my generated Excel each condition (makes it easier when working through several logs as I increment the row number).

Something like:

```
            Percentage
ID Feature            
0  False           20
```

and then separately for Feature == 'True':

```
            Percentage
ID Feature            
0  True           30
```

I tried with this method, but i get the error - TypeError: invalid type comparison

```
percentages = pd.DataFrame({'Percentage': mydf[(mydf['ID'] == 0)&(mydf['Feature'] == 'False')].groupby(('ID','Feature')).size() / (len(df)*100)})
```

Comment: I'm not sure that code would produce the answers you say it does.  Your `/ (len(df)*100)` looks like it has the 100 in the wrong place (you're dividing by an extra factor of 100, not multiplying a fraction by 100 to get a percentage.)

Comment: You're correct DSM - I had the closing bracket in the wrong place, I have edited the code above, it should've been (len(df))*100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use your `percentages` result df and just index into the multi-index df:

```
In [81]:
percentages = pd.DataFrame({'Percentage': df.groupby(('ID', 'Feature')).size() / (len(df)*100)})
percentages

Out[81]:
            Percentage
ID Feature            
0  False         0.002
   True          0.003
1  False         0.003
   True          0.002

In [83]:    
print(percentages.loc[(0,False)])
print(percentages.loc[(0,True)])
Percentage    0.002
Name: (0, False), dtype: float64
Percentage    0.003
Name: (0, True), dtype: float64
```

The syntax here uses a tuple to index into each level, here `(0,False)` indexes ID `0` and then the next value is level 1 `False` and so on.

There is a further explanation and sample code [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

You can get the index values using `get_level_values`:

```
In [86]:
print(percentages.index.get_level_values(0))
print(percentages.index.get_level_values(1))

Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype='int64', name='ID')
Index([False, True, False, True], dtype='object', name='Feature')
```

you can just call `unique` on the above to get the unique values and just iterate over them:

```
In [87]:
for level_0 in percentages.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    for level_1 in percentages.index.get_level_values(1).unique():
        print(percentages.loc[level_0, level_1])

Percentage    0.002
Name: (0, False), dtype: float64
Percentage    0.003
Name: (0, True), dtype: float64
Percentage    0.003
Name: (1, False), dtype: float64
Percentage    0.002
Name: (1, True), dtype: float64
```

The above assumes that `True`/`False` exist for all IDs, otherwise you'll raise a `KeyError`

Comment: Thanks EdChum, you saved me again from hours of confusion! Your solution worked exactly as i was hoping for.