# Create dataframe with summary data

Tags: python, r, bash, pandas, dplyr

I have a large dataframe (millions of rows x a dozen columns), that I'd like to get some summary data on.  Overall, I have up to 800,000 possible "Name"s as seen in this example, and 6 possible values across up to 440 Samples.

Here's a toy example of what I have and what I want:

Starting table:

```
Name   Chr   Pos   Sample  Value
RS1    1     1000   S1      1
RS1    1     1000   S2      1    
RS1    1     1000   S3      2
RS1    1     1000   S4      3
RS1    1     1000   S5      1
RS1    1     1000   S6      2
```

I want the proportion of each Value for each item in the Name column.  In this example, there are 6 Samples, with 3 possible Values.  Thus, my output would be:

```
Name   Chr    Pos   Value   Proportion
RS1    1      1000   1      0.5
RS1    1      1000   2      0.33
RS1    1      1000   3      0.17
```

I'm open to doing this in R (dplyr?) or Python (using base or pandas??)  or even bash scripting if that makes sense.  I'm looking for something that will be time and memory efficient.  I have some proficiency in R, but am a beginning learning Python and all it can do.

Comment: Are you after this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122300/pandas-percentage-count-on-a-dataframe-groupby if so I will close as dupe

Comment: For something that big, R's `data.table`, or maybe SQL. You can do it easily with `dplyr`, but for that size, it will probably be slow.

Comment: I think that pandas answer will work.  I'm trying it out.  Obviously, I searched the wrong terms.  I worry that R will choke on this much data, or be horribly slow, but will take a look if I can't get pandas to work.  I have no way to get this into a database so I can use SQL, but that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the more elegant answer but it worked for me:

```
toy <- tbl_df(toy)
toy$Chr <- as.factor(toy$Chr)
toy$Pos <- as.factor(toy$Pos)
toy$Value <- as.factor(toy$Value)

df <- as.data.frame(toy %>% 
  group_by(Name, Chr, Pos, Value) %>% 
  tally %>% 
  group_by(Name, Value))

df %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n))
```

Comment: This worked for me in R on one of my smaller data sets, although was slow.  I hope it'll still work on my large dataset.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `plyr`. Below, `d` is the starting table and `output` is the result.

```
library(plyr)
output = ddply(d, "Name", function(x){
  tab = table(x$Value)/length(x$Value)
  prop = as.numeric(tab)
  val = names(tab)
  data.frame(Name = x$Name[1], Chr = x$Chr[1], Pos = x$Pos[1], Value = val, Proportion = prop)
})
```